# NHibernate 3 and MySQL setup tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, nhibernate

Since I have given up on using the entity framework 4 as my ORM (getting it to work with MySQL and mapping table/field names like this_table/this_field to object naming like ThisTable/ThisField is POCO) I am now looking at NHibernate as it seems the the next big well know ORM for C# that probably with not die off any time soon.  I am trying to lookup some tutorials and a lot of them in the configuration section have 2-2 in it and was wondering if those configuration would work with NHibernate 3?  I am just curious if the 2-2 refers to the version of NHibernate or something different.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to this:

```
urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2
```

as often seen seen in the mappings. That's not the version of NHibernate, it's the version of the XML schema. The previous stable version of NHibernate was 2.1.2, and as far as I can tell there hasn't yet been a 2.2 (although in the future there might yet be one -- as I understand it, NH 3 targets .NET 3.5 and I'd imagine there are a lot of people who can't upgrade yet).

Comment: Why can't a lot of people upgrade yet?  .NET is up to 4.0 now.  3.5 is  now 3 years old.  I'm extremely curious...

Comment: Well, the cost of upgrading to a bugfix release in the 2.1.2 branch would be significantly cheaper than upgrading your entire application to a newer runtime. But really, I was just speculating. :)